# Is it a good practice to make WCF calls while using Autocomplete/ Select2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2

- I have dropdowns for Countries, and Cities in my MVC website.
- I am using Select2 JQuery plug-in to take advantage of autocomplete,
  and multiple selection facilities.
- The dropdown list gets filtered as user types in, and at each
  keystroke there is a controller action returning Json array gets
  called (through AJAX)
- I am calling a WCF method to fetch data from database to use it as a
  source of the Select2.

Do you reckon is it a good approach to call WCF methods this frequently?

Actually, I do not want to use session or tempdata in my application, as they bring other complexities with them, and so I thought to make WCF calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no. In general you don't want to make a request on every single keystroke. Look at the `quietMillis` option. It appears as though the latest unreleased code has added caching support (although the documentation confusingly refers to caching "web pages" not "data") which would also help by being able to further filter already returned results instead of needing to make another server call.